# Custom view disappearing on using smoothscrollby

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

I am doing a visualisation graph for audio being recorded. I have a custom View for visualisation. The visualisation (just a graph) derives from amplitude and keeps moving and can extend beyond screen width.  SO I introduced the Custom View inside `HorizontalScrollView`. The view is scrollable now. But once the graph coordinates went beyond screen it didn't scroll automatically. So I introduced `smoothscrollby` or `smoothscrollto` after the visualisation is rendered. But this causes the custom view to be erased. And the scroll bar moves but again when it goes beyond screen width the bar also disappears. Why is `smoothScrollby` erasing whats drawn? Its a green color graph moving with a red line drawn at end. It completely disappears when i have `smoothscrollby`. I put it in a `mHorizontalScrollView.post (new runnable)` but that also didn't work.  I have included code and my `content_recording.xml` Let me know if any more information is required.

**Part of the Custom View Code**

```
   @Override
   public void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure( 1999999999, heightMeasureSpec);

}

   @Override
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    final int middle = viewHeight / 2; //middle of view
    float curX = 0; //start cursor at x axist at 0


    //for each item in amplitudes Arraylist
    for (float power : amplitudes) {
        float scaledHeight = power / LINE_SCALE; //scale the power
        curX += LINE_WIDTH; //imcrease by line widht

        // draw a line representing this item in the amplitudes ArrayList
        canvas.drawLine(curX, middle + scaledHeight / 2, curX, middle - scaledHeight / 2, linePaint);

    }


    lastAmplitudeIndex = amplitudes.size();
    canvas.drawLine(curX, middle + viewHeight / 2, curX, middle - viewHeight / 2, currentLinePointer);
    mHorizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy((int) curX, 0);
  }
```

**Content_recording:**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/chronometer"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id ="@+id/horscrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        >

        <com.example.tasv.musicandroidactivity.VisualizerView
            android:id="@+id/visualizer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```